# How do I filter Python screen print?

Tags: python, bash

I want to filter the screen print by my Python program.

Ideally, it would be nice to specify a "print blacklist", such as this one.

```
*FutureWarning*
INFO*
```

When part of a screen printout matches one of the above patterns, the whole printout is filtered out.

I'm surprised no one has yet to ask this question, as I think this is extremely useful, because without it, I need to go through different types of screen printouts and deal with them accordingly. You can imagine some of them may be due to `print`, some due to `warning`, etc.

I am running my Python script from bash, so bash-based methods are welcome too!

Comment: What do you mean by "screen print"?  Your description seems to refer to messages printed through a variety of channels to the symbiont output device (often a command window), but the terminology doesn't match.  Your half-example doesn't give enough detail to be sure, and the form of question doesn't really match SO's specificity standard.

Comment: I think maybe he's looking for something like `grep -v -E "(list|of|blacklisted|words)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to filter the screen print by my Python program.

You can use Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module, routing all print and warnings output through it:

```
# in your main module
import logging

# -- log all output to myapp.log
logging.basicConfig(filename='myapp.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
# -- OR log all output to console
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
# route all output to logging
logging.captureWarnings(True)
print  = logging.info
```

With this add your own `Filter` to filter all output as per the required keywords:

```
# define Filter in its own module, say logfilter.py
class OutputFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, keywords, name=None):
        super(OutputFilter, self).__init__(name)
        self.keywords = keywords

    def filter(self, record):
        msg = record.getMessage()
        return not any(k in msg for k in self.keywords)

# add this in your main module
from logfilter import OutputFilter
flt = OutputFilter(['*FutureWarning*', 'INFO*'])
logger = logging.getLogger() # root logger
logger.addFilter(flt)
warnLogger = logging.getLogger('py.warnings') # warnings logger
warnLogger.addFilter(flt)
```

> (...) without it, I need to go through different types of screen printouts and deal with them accordingly.

If you can change the source code it is better to always use a module logger instead of print:

```
# in any module with output, right after imports
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
# instead of print
logger.info(...)
logger.error(...)
logger.debug(...)
```

The advantage is `logging` allows you very fine grained control on what to output and where, while configuring everything from a central place.

For example, while the above uses the root logger that applies to all logging output, every module of your application can have its own logger, with its specific configuration, e.g.

```
# somewhere in your main module
# -- basic config is to console
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
# -- module A output should go into its own file
logger = logging.getLogger('path.to.module.A')
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='myapp-A.log') # see above
logger.setHandler(handler) 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# path/to/module/A.py
# -- right at the top of the module
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
...
# in the actual code
logger.info('info message')
```

This example will route all INFO messages by module A into file `myapp-A.log` while all other output goes to the terminal.

Note: All examples where adopted from the [Python Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook). Also check out the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) for more in-depth explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `print` variable to a custom function of yours that checks for any output you don't want to see.

Here is an example:

```
>>> def print(*args, **kwargs):
...     import builtins
...     if not any(str(s).startswith('INFO') for s in args):
...             builtins.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if there are other commands other than `print` that print out stuff?

Comment: @SibbsGambling you can look into replacing `sys.stdout` with a custom object that subclasses `io.TextIOWrapper` but I don't recommend it. Check out the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're willing to do bash. You could write another script, say `filter.py`:

```
from sys import stdin

def print_filtered(line):
    if line.startswith("print this"):
        print(line, end='') # The line includes its own newline character

for line in stdin:
    print_filtered(line)
```

Of course, you can put whatever filtering options you want in `print_filtered()`. You could even do some replacements; maybe you would want to remove the `print this` section of the string before you print it.

Now any program that you want to have filtered output, you can run like this:

```
$ python myfile.py | python filter.py
```

---

Rishav also mentioned in his comment that you could replace `sys.stdout` with a custom object. I don't really like that idea, but you could do that with something like this:

```
import sys

class FilteredPrinter(object):
    def __init__(self, filtered_print, stdout):
        self._filtered_print = filtered_print
        self._stdout = stdout

    def _write(self, string):
        self._filtered_print(string, self._stdout)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'write':
            return self._write
        return getattr(self._stdout, attr)


def filtered_print(string, stdout):
    if string == "\n" or string.startswith("print this"):
        stdout.write(string)

sys.stdout = FilteredPrinter(filtered_print, sys.stdout)
print("print this: my text") 
print("print this text")
print("Don't print this")
```

With this solution, you can specify whatever filters you want; you could also do this with `sys.stderr`. If you want to go back to the old, use `sys.stdout = sys.stdout._stdout`. Do be aware that the `print` function calls `sys.stdout.write()` once for each of its arguments and again for the newline character. That is, calling `print("first", "second")` will do this:

```
sys.stdout.write("first")
sys.stdout.write(" ")
sys.stdout.write("second")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

So just be sure to keep that in mind when writing your filter function.

Comment: +1 thanks! But wouldn't `python myfile.py | python filter.py` make ` filter.py` run after `myfile.py` is done? By that time, things are already printed on the screen? In my case, `myfile.py` is a long-running script that constantly prints on the screen.

Comment: @sibbs: The output is piped, so it will definitely not be printed unless myfilter.py prints it. I'm pretty sure myfilter.py handles it in real time, but you could run a test.

Comment: Hmmm, is that because I did `cmd="python myfile.py | python filter.py"; eval ${cmd}`? It doesn't stop printing in the real time.

Comment: @sibbs: I'm not sure. Is there a reason you need to use eval instead of calling directly?

Comment: Hmmm, I stopped using `eval`, but it still cannot stop real-time printouts...

Comment: @sibbs: I'm not sure I understand. Is the program printing when it should?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When I run `python myfile.py | python filter.py`, even if I blacklisted some lines in `filter.py`, but they still get printed out real-time.

Comment: @sibbs Would you mind showing me what your filter.py looks like (maybe with pastebin)?

Comment: Thanks a lot! https://pastebin.com/kgtzwn1M

Comment: @sibb: Hm. It looks fine. What text is getting by that shouldn't?